# Why HttpServletResponse has empty body after successful Login

Tags: java, spring, react-native, spring-security, react-redux

I've got an app that uses Spring And React/Redux. Authentication is done by `WebSecurityConfig` which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Configure method:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .successHandler(new CustomSuccessAuthenticationHandler())
```

CustomSuccessAuthenticationHandler looks like this:

```
CustomSuccessAuthenticationHandlerextends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.getWriter().write(JsonHelper.objectToJson(new CustomDto()));
    }
}
```

And problem is, that in browser, in response do not have any body. I can set HTTP status or headers using `HttpServletResponse` and it is set, but if i write body - it is always empty. I've tried using `response.getOutputStream().write()`, flusing etc. but nothing works. Even if I redirect to endpoint with needed data, body is always empty. Can it have something to do with React routing done by front?

Comment: Calling `response.getWriter().flush()` should flush the stream. Are you sure you tried to flush it?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work